# AJAX requests inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call multiple ajax requests inside a loop to load multiple dropdown lists. I tried the sequential way and i can see that the last item in loop only is getting filled with values

```
 var targetcontrols = [];
        var targetcontrols_array = targetControl.split(',');
        var targetsourcecontrols = [];
        var targetsource_array = targetSource.split(',');
        for(i=0; i < targetcontrols_array.length; i++)
        {
            var control_name=targetcontrols_array[i];
            var source=targetsource_array[i];
            $.ajax({
                url: action_url,
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify( { allselected: allselected_flag, selectedIds: selectedvalues,targetControl:control_name,  targetSource: source, dependency: dependencyOptions } ),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    //To clear existing items
                    var target= $("#"+response.targetControl);
                    target.multiselect('dataprovider', []);
                    var dropdown2OptionList = [];
                    for (i = 0; i < response.values.length; i++) {
                        dropdown2OptionList.push({
                            'label': response.values[i].text,
                            'value': response.values[i].value
                        })
                    }
                    console.log("--control"+control_name);
                    //re initialize the search plugin
                    target.multiselect('dataprovider', dropdown2OptionList);
                    target.multiselect('rebuild');
                }
            });
```

How can i ensure the first item in the loop also is getting filled with response values

Comment: are you sure that `var target= $("#"+response.targetControl);` always different control?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `map` to produce an array of `Promise`. After that use `Promise.all()` to execute this promises array.

```js
var targetcontrols = [];
var targetcontrols_array = targetControl.split(',');
var targetsourcecontrols = [];
var targetsource_array = targetSource.split(',');
const arrOfPromises = targetcontrols_array.map(function(item, index) {
  const control_name = item;
  const source = targetsource_array[index];
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: action_url,
      type: 'POST',
      traditional: true,
      async: false,
      data: JSON.stringify( { allselected: allselected_flag, selectedIds: selectedvalues,targetControl:control_name,  targetSource: source, dependency: dependencyOptions } ),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (response) {
        //To clear existing items
        var target= $("#"+response.targetControl);
        target.multiselect('dataprovider', []);
        var dropdown2OptionList = [];
        for (i = 0; i < response.values.length; i++) {
          dropdown2OptionList.push({
            'label': response.values[i].text,
            'value': response.values[i].value
          })
        }
        console.log("--control"+control_name);
        //re initialize the search plugin
        target.multiselect('dataprovider', dropdown2OptionList);
        target.multiselect('rebuild');
        resolve(`done for url ${control_name}`) // Show log for checking process
      }
  })
})
  
Promise.all(arrOfPromises)
```

Answer (score 1):

These 2 declarations:

```
var control_name = targetcontrols_array[i];
var source = targetsource_array[i];
```

maybe cause the problem. Because `var` has `function scope` and `for loop` is a `block scope`, so when you use the loop, these `control_name` and `source` variables got replaced from the next one, before used in ajax request. That's why you always get the last. You should change `var` into `const` or `let` which support `block scope`

```
const control_name = targetcontrols_array[i];
const source = targetsource_array[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you use jquery, utilize it's full potential, instead of `for` loops, use 
[`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var targetcontrols = [];
        var targetcontrols_array = targetControl.split(',');
        var targetsourcecontrols = [];
        var targetsource_array = targetSource.split(',');
        $.each(targetcontrols_array, function(i, item)
        {
            var control_name=targetcontrols_array[i];
            var source=targetsource_array[i];
            $.ajax({
                url: action_url,
                type: 'POST',
                traditional: true,
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify( { allselected: allselected_flag, selectedIds: selectedvalues,targetControl:control_name,  targetSource: source, dependency: dependencyOptions } ),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    //To clear existing items
                    var target= $("#"+response.targetControl);
                    target.multiselect('dataprovider', []);
                    var dropdown2OptionList = [];
                    $.each(response.values, function(v, vItems) {
                        dropdown2OptionList.push({
                            'label': response.values[v].text,
                            'value': response.values[v].value
                        })
                    });
                    console.log("--control"+control_name);
                    //re initialize the search plugin
                    target.multiselect('dataprovider', dropdown2OptionList);
                    target.multiselect('rebuild');
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: but stil the  last item in loop is getting reflected Is it because of async nature of  ajax calls